# Adding Calculate button to execute script

Tags: javascript, function

I have a piece of script that runs on page load, but due to the variables it uses throughout the page I need to add the ability to run the script on command instead of automatically on page load.  I'm a javascript novice so I'm not sure how to do it

I've found a tried a few scripting options, but have not gotten them to work

```
        $('.cf-table-block').on('blur change', '.domain2Sum select, .domain3Sum, .domain4sum, .domain1sum, .achievementSum select', calcScore);

    function calcScore() {
    var s = (parseNumber($('.professionalSubtotal input').val()) * .90) + (parseNumber($('.achievementSubtotal input').val()) * .10);
    $('.teacherScore input').val((s).toFixed(2));
  }

  function parseNumber(n) {
    var f = parseFloat(n); //Convert to float number.
    return isNaN(f) ? 0 : f; //treat invalid input as 0;
  }
```

The calculation works, but I just need to add a calculate button to execute the calculation at will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a button to your page somewhere and call the method on the click event

```
<button type='button' id='calculate-button' onclick='calcScore()'>Calculate</button>
```

You can add the click event to the button via jquery as well (it looks like you're using jquery) but this should get you started in the right direction.

To do that with jquery you don't include the onclick in the markup. Instead you can use [jquery click event](https://api.jquery.com/click/)

```
$(function() {
  $('#calculate-button').click(function() { calcScore(); });
}
```

You'll need to add that to a script tag in the head of your document. This relies on the "calcScore" method being in scope for the document though, and we can't tell that from your code snippet. You'll also need to make sure this script is after the other script.

Comment: Ah ok, I may be using jquery(I'm a noob)..and that may need to be the direction I need to go.  I added the code you provided to the HTML... the button shows up, but when I change values in the fields it should be pulling from and click calculate the original value doesn't change.  How would I add it via jquery?

Comment: Thanks that worked!  Thought I'd share my code for information/use. Much appreciated!

Comment: @TJLP - will you accept my answer if it helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
    .dontshow {display: none;}
    .done {color: tomato !important; font-weight: bold;}
    .blink {
    animation: blinker 1.5s step-start infinite;
    }

    @keyframes blinker {
    50% {
    opacity: 0;
    }
    }
$(document).ready(function () {

    //Countdown Timer

  var startTime = 15; //set countdown in Minutes  
  var doneClass = "done";
  var blinkerClass = "blink";
  function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    var intervalLoop = setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
        for(var i=0;i<display.length;i++){
          display[i].textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;
        }
        if (--timer < 0) {
          for(var i=0;i<display.length;i++){
            display[i].classList.add(doneClass);
            display[i].classList.add(blinkerClass);
            display[i].textContent = "SAVE NOW";
          }
          clearInterval(intervalLoop);
        }
        }, 1000);
    }
window.onload = function () {
    var setMinutes = 60 * startTime,
    display = $('#timer');
    startTimer(setMinutes, display);
};

  //End Countdown timer  

  //Start Add row amount fields together for domain 1
        $('.cf-table-block').on('blur change', '.domain1Sum select', domain1sumtotal);

    function domain1sumtotal() {
        var s = 0;
        $('.domain1Sum select').each(function () {
            s += parseNumber($(this).val());
        });
        s = s/6;
        $('.domain1Subtotal input').val((s).toFixed(2));
    }
    function parseNumber(n) {
        var f = parseFloat(n); //Convert to float number.
        return isNaN(f) ? 0 : f; //treat invalid input as 0;
    }
    //End Add row amount fields together for domain 1

    //Start Add row amount fields together for domain 2
        $('.cf-table-block').on('blur change', '.domain2Sum select', domain2sumtotal);

    function domain2sumtotal() {
        var s = 0;
        $('.domain2Sum select').each(function () {
            s += parseNumber($(this).val());
        });
        s = s/5;
        $('.domain2Subtotal input').val((s).toFixed(2));
    }
    function parseNumber(n) {
        var f = parseFloat(n); //Convert to float number.
        return isNaN(f) ? 0 : f; //treat invalid input as 0;
    }
    //End Add row amount fields together for domain 2

   //Start Add row amount fields together for domain 3
        $('.cf-table-block').on('blur change', '.domain3Sum select', domain3sumtotal);

    function domain3sumtotal() {
        var s = 0;
        $('.domain3Sum select').each(function () {
            s += parseNumber($(this).val());
        });
        s = s/5;
        $('.domain3Subtotal input').val((s).toFixed(2));
    }
    function parseNumber(n) {
        var f = parseFloat(n); //Convert to float number.
        return isNaN(f) ? 0 : f; //treat invalid input as 0;
    }
    //End Add row amount fields together for domain 3

    //Start Add row amount fields together for domain 4
        $('.cf-table-block').on('blur change', '.domain4Sum select', domain4sumtotal);

    function domain4sumtotal() {
        var s = 0;
        $('.domain4Sum select').each(function () {
            s += parseNumber($(this).val());
        });
        s = s/6;
        $('.domain4Subtotal input').val((s).toFixed(2));
    }
    function parseNumber(n) {
        var f = parseFloat(n); //Convert to float number.
        return isNaN(f) ? 0 : f; //treat invalid input as 0;
    }
    //End Add row amount fields together for domain 4

    //Start Add domain 1, 2, 3 and domain 4 totals
        $('.cf-table-block').on('blur change', '.domainSum select', domainsumtotal);

    function domainsumtotal() {
        var s = 0;
        $('.domainSum select').each(function () {
            s += parseNumber($(this).val());
        });
        s = s/22;
        $('.professionalSubtotal input').val((s).toFixed(2));
    }
    function parseNumber(n) {
        var f = parseFloat(n); //Convert to float number.
        return isNaN(f) ? 0 : f; //treat invalid input as 0;
    }
    //End Add domain 1, 2, 3 and domain 4 totals

    //Start Add row amount fields together for teacher score
        $('.cf-table-block').on('blur change', '.domain2Sum select, .domain3Sum, .domain4sum, .domain1sum, .achievementSum select', calcScore);

    function calcScore() {
        var s = (parseNumber($('.professionalSubtotal input').val()) * .90) + (parseNumber($('.achievementSubtotal input').val()) * .10);
        $('.teacherScore input').val((s).toFixed(2));
        $('#calculate-button').click(function() { calcScore(); });
   }

    function parseNumber(n) {
        var f = parseFloat(n); //Convert to float number.
        return isNaN(f) ? 0 : f; //treat invalid input as 0;

   } 
     //End Add row amount fields together for score    


});
```